# Copy-Item Issue using a variable as destination folder name

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I am stuck with something weird you may help me.

I am doing the following:

```
  $DateStringInput=Read-host

Copy-Item -Path "C:\Hodzic\PowerShell\Testordner\Q_Schulungspräsentationen\Vorlage" -Destination "C:\Hodzic\PowerShell\Testordner\Q_Schulungspräsentationen\$DateStringInput_KSF_Grundlagen"  -Recurse
```

This doesnt work as the error says you cannot overwirte [Folder] with itself...the error repeats for each file contained in the copy-item path.

If I now put a space or anything else in front of "_" in the last part of the destination part it works:

...$DateStringInput _KSF_Grundlagen" or $DateStringInput+_KSF_Grundlagen"

Can you help?

Comment: What's the full error message?

Comment: Sounds like the folder already exist. Try adding the `-Force` flag to overwrite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PowerShell parser interprets all of `$DateStringInput_KSF_Grundlagen` as a single variable expression.

Enclose the variable name in `{}` to prevent that:

```
$Destination = "C:\Hodzic\PowerShell\Testordner\Q_Schulungspräsentationen\${DateStringInput}_KSF_Grundlagen"
Copy-Item -Path "C:\Hodzic\PowerShell\Testordner\Q_Schulungspräsentationen\Vorlage" -Destination $Destination
```